# How to retrieve only the IPV4 from ip addr in Linux

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ip

I am trying to pass the IPV4 for the `tun0` interface into a script.

```
./start.sh `ip addr | grep tun0 | grep inet`
```

The issue I have is I cannot think how to separate this further to only get `10.10.14.252`.

```
inet 10.10.14.252/23 scope global tun0
```

Any help appreciated to perhaps use `sed` to retrieve only the `10.10.14.252`. The IPV4 is dynamic, the script can be executed on any environment and may not always start with `10.10`

```
ip addr | grep tun0|grep inet|tr ' ' "\n"|grep 10.|tr '/' "\n"|grep 10
```

This works, its long but works. But am I guaranteed that the IPV4 will always start with 10?

Comment: The /23 looks like a netmask; are you sure this is the correct field to parse out?

Comment: Perhaps see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970088/is-the-output-of-tools-like-ip-meant-to-be-parsed and the `--json` option of `ip`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest:

```
ip -o -4 addr list tun0 | awk -F ' *|/' '{print $4}'
```

Comment: Didn't work for me e.g. in Alpine due to using `*` which is matching zero whitespace, too, thus `$4` is referring to the fourth character. Replacing `*` with `+` was helping. In addition, I don't know the name of the device, so I was using a different check to pick the line:

`ip -o -4 addr list | awk -F ' +|/' '/scope +global/{print $4}'`

Answer (score 3):

Using `jq` with `ip -json`:

```
$ ip -j -4 -o addr | jq -r '.[] | select(.addr_info[].dev=="tun0") | .addr_info[].local'
```

Comment: or `ip -o -j -4 addr list tun0 | jq -r '.[].addr_info[].local'`

Comment: @Cyrus Even better. Got tired of reading that `man ip`...

Answer (score 2):

Try Awk.

```sh
ip addr |
awk '/inet/ && /tun0/ {
  ip = $2; sub(/\/.*/, "", ip); print ip }'
```

Generally, if you have a pipe with `grep` going into `sed` or Awk, [get rid of the `grep`.](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep)

Answer (score 1):

One `sed` idea using a capture group for the ip address:

```
$ ip addr | sed -En '/inet .* tun0/{s/^inet ([^ /]*).*/\1/p}'
```

**NOTE:** assumes the ip address follows immediately after the `inet` string and is followed by a space or a forward slash

For test purposes let's assume `ip addr > ip.out` generates:

```
$ cat ip.out
some stuff on line 1
inet 10.10.14.252/23 scope global tun0
some stuff on line 3
```

Simulating `ip addr`:

```
$ cat ip.out | sed -En '/inet .* tun0/{s/^inet ([^ /]*).*/\1/p}'
10.10.14.252
```